# name 'Bidirectional' is not defined

Tags: python, machine-learning, lstm

Im following [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/cryptocurrency-price-prediction-using-lstms-tensorflow-for-hackers-part-iii-264fcdbccd3f) tutorial and right when I want to initialize a sequential keras, like the code below:

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(
    CuDNNLSTM(Win_size, return_sequences=True),
    input_shape=(Win_size, X_train.shape[-1])))
```

I get an error saying :

```
NameError: name 'Bidirectional' is not defined
```

What is the problem ? it is the exact same code as in the tutorial.

Comment: None of the code fragments on that page include the necessary `import` statements to bring in the object definitions being used.  You're going to have to search through the documentation for the relevant modules to find exactly where things like `Bidirectional` are defined, and write your own imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re most likely missing the import statement from the tensorflow package.

It appears that’s there is a link to the source code in that article which shows the full import statement.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Bidirectional
```

Keep in mind that the source code linked includes more imports but this would be directly related to the error you mentioned.